# Raspberry Pi 3 model B + Java + RC522

Tags: java, raspberry-pi

Здравствуйте, есть проблема: работать с RFID RC522 с **Java** на Raspberry pi 3 Model B. Проблема заключается в поиске библиотеки, гугл результатов не дал. Нужно только чтение инфо с карт.

Comment: `jSSC` не умеет ?

Comment: @faoxis Если я правильно понял, работа идет с сериал портом, а у меня через GPIO подключено

Comment: Я подключал через `jSSC` контроллер `stm32` к компьютеру через `RS232`. Но тогда я просто принимал информацию с контроллера. Я думаю, что при работе с ножками `Raspberry pi` вы обращаетесь к ним напрямую через регистры (без участия ОС). Сомневаюсь, что работа в таком режиме хорошо подходит для `java` из-за `jvm` и платформонезависимости. Мне кажется вам стоит посмотреть на `python` или `C/C++`. В обоих случаях есть готовые библиотеки для работы с `GPIO` для `Raspberry pi`.

Comment: Всё уже, нашёл, питон и плюсы знаю, но вся система написана на джаве, и из-за этого нужно было именно её, спасибо за помощь))

Comment: А что нашел ? Сделай ответ на свой вопрос. Кто-то еще может искать подобную информацию.

Comment: Вот какой то код [GitHub](https://github.com/LiangYuen/Pi4j-RC522), но не могу прочесть инфо с карты, только УИД, аутентификация не проходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ на собственный вопрос нашел сам, по моему скромному мнению лучшим решением будет библиотека [DIOZero](https://github.com/mattjlewis/diozero), она имеет средства для работы не только с RFID-RC522, а и с многими другими сенсорами.